# Dependencies in Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

What I know so far is, to make any application SSO enabled, there must be an Identity provider taking part in the SSO game. So there is direct dependency on IDP as the SP need to **"know"** who the IDP is. Can SP have a common saml communication mechanism which can work with any IDP that my customer is using ? Or I need to build different saml communicator based on the customer supported IDP ?

Reason: One of our company customer is using Okta for its employees and want us to make our application Okta enabled so that its employees need not to remember credentials on our site anymore. That's fine. Now, if any other customer comes with some other IDP (PingOne for example), do we need to work again to make it that xyz IDP enabled ? or our existing implementation will work same way by just adding that IDPs url ? Let me know if I am missing any big picture or key concept here.
P.S. Our application is on .NET platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to create a new association if a user want to use a new IDP.
There is a good reason for this. You need to be say that you trust the IDP. The IDP is the one that vouches that the user is who they say they are. So you have to ensure that you trust it to authenticate users for you system.

What you could do is to allow for the customer to define its the IDP to be used, provided that the IDP is only allowed to authenticate that customers users.
If you want to do this I would recommend using some third party software.